# Which encryption key size is used by GLib?

Tags: encryption, key, size, glib

Does someone now with key size (128-bit?) is used by GLib in GSocketConnection/GTlsConnection? Is this fix implemented or changeable?

Answer (score 1):

In GLib, you are effectively negotiating a TLS (Transport Layer Security) session key/cipher.

Therefore this will depend on the connection partners preferences and supported cipher suite.

Cipher suites will be dependent on the version of TLS used too.

More information on TLS [cipher suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) here.

Answer (score 0):

The TLS implementation in GLib actually just uses either GnuTLS or OpenSSL, so the key size is handled by them. GLib does not override their defaults or decisions.